# Append “tail” to multiple selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple result rows that has following structure

```
 select data0, data1, ..., data30 from t0
 union all select data0, ..., data30 from t1
 ...
```

There are multiple result rows, many of which need 
to be aligned to the length of 30. So me do following

```
 union all select data0, data1, null, null, ..., null
```

Is there a convenient way to automate this kind of
task. What I want is to append tail nulls as needed.

What I do now

```
 with nulls as (
  select null as nul0, ..., null as nul30 from dual
 )
```

And I am stuck at this point. How to append this nulls to
result rows? Number of empty columns are known.

Pls edit as appropriate, I type from mobile

Comment: what is your dbms name

Comment: Do a cross join (instead of merge.)

Comment: Oracle is the dbms name

Comment: I should clarify a question

Comment: You need all in one column? or 6 separate column?

Comment: `SELECT 0,1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: @ЯрославМашко . . . (1) Your code does not work in Oracle.  (2) `merge` is not an operator that combines queries.  (3) Why not just use `select 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 from dual`?  You are selecting constants anyway.

Comment: Made some serious edit. Trying to make my question clear. Just not used to type on mobile that much.

Comment: @GordonLinoff made an edit. I need to append some number of nulls to many rows. Number of columns can be up to 30-100. I do not want, can not type that many nulls all the time.

Comment: They come from different tables, CTEs.

Answer (score 2):

> How to append this nulls to result rows?

There is no built-in solution for generating a projection of an arbitrary number of columns.

This solution will take a fair amount of typing but you can semi-automate it by using a text editor which supports regex search'n'replace patterns.

```
with nulls as (
    select cast(null as varchar2(10)) as nul0
           , ...
           , cast(null as varchar2(10)) as nul30 
    from dual
) 
select t1.dat01
       , t1.dat02
       , nulls.nul03 as dat03
       , nulls.nul04 as dat04
       ...
       , nulls.nul30 as dat30
from t1
     cross join nulls 
union all
select t2.dat01
       , t2.dat02
       , t2.dat03
       , nulls.nul04 as dat04
       ...
       , nulls.nul30 as dat30
from t2
     cross join nulls
```

Comment: Well, I typed my question falsely assuming that someone will understand my thoughts typed in a hurry. The point is that I need to append one result to align with some number of columns.

Comment: Well the cross join would have kinda work, in other situation, but my result rows have different number of nulls that I append.

Comment: On second thought it should work with cross join way, but I still have to type those CTEs with LOTs of nulls.

Comment: This may be a solution. As I understand, as a novice, with such syntax there will be no multiple rows as a result of cross join. Still lots of typing though. Gotta check this syntax, it’s new to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response, gotta check it. Will return in some time.

Comment: Hello. Have checked your solution. Can you explain why you did a cross join? I did a quick test and my result is a query with `union all` that has rows with nulls. But cross join seems excess. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ENGr8Yd8dmgmvUhLcdsU9/0

Comment: To be honest it's a month ago and I can't remember my thought processes. I think I was adapting something I did when the task was to supply default values. If you have a simpler approach use it.